# Is there a resource (e.g. a website) to identify a lego set based on a selection of parts?

Tags: set-identification

Is there a resource (e.g. a website) to identify a Lego set based on a selection of parts?

For example, I have inherited a big box of Legos including several castle-type pieces. Is there a way to figure out what sets those may gave come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BrickLink itself has such a [feature](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogIn.asp?viewMulti=Y) - had I known, I would not have written my own a year ago.

[Brickit](https://brickit.app/) is a new entry in this arena; I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for!